# How to concate an array

Tags: php, arrays

I am facing some issue with an array

```
    $myarray =array();
    for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++){
          $myarray =array(
                        'userId'=>10,
                         'sum'=>40);
          echo"<pre>";print_r($myarray);    
       }
```

This is my dummy array just want to understand you what actually facing issue this loop all time generate an array that have elements `$userid` or `$sum`

after run the above code it alwayz showing same array as i am using static value but on live its generate array with diffrent `$userid` or `$sum`

Like this

```
Array
(
 [sum] => 0
 [userId] => 1
)
Array
(
 [sum] => 5
 [userId] => 4
)
Array
(
 [sum] => 30
 [userId] => 5
)
Array
(
 [sum] => 0
 [userId] => 16
)
Array
(
 [sum] => 0
 [userId] => 17
)
Array
(
 [sum] => 16
 [userId] => 34
)
```

I want to merge all these array in one array so that i can easily find out

Max   `$sum` from all these array generated inside loop and corresponding `$userid` .

Output after loop should be

```
'first winner $sum =  30  $userid =5 `    
'second winner $sum =  16  $userid =34` 
'first winner $sum =  5  $userid =4 `
```

please suggest a way how i can do that as all are different array coming with loop

Thanks

Comment: use brackets? `myarray[] = array( ... );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In every iteration you are overwriting base array content.

```
$myarray = array();

for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
    $myarray[] = array(
        'userId' => rand(1, 100),
        'sum' => rand(1, 100),
    );
}

echo "<pre>"; var_dump($myarray);
```

`$myarray` will contain:

```
Array(
   [0] => ['userId' => 5, 'sum' => 45],
   [1] => ['userId' => 1, 'sum' => 85],
   ...
   [11] => ['userId' => 8, 'sum' => 41],
);
```

To sort that array by `sum` key, use [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

```
usort($myarray, function ($a, $b) {
    return $a['sum'] - $b['sum'];
});
```

Comment: How can fine now first three user that have maximum sum like 1.)first winner 2.)Second winner 3.)Thirs winner

Comment: You guys are really amazing :)

Comment: @Chauhan just apply mapping function from here http://www.karlrixon.co.uk/writing/convert-numbers-to-words-with-php/

Answer (score 1):

Can you try it?

```
$sumArray=array(
   0 => array('userId' => 5, 'sum' => 45),
   1 => array('userId' => 1, 'sum' => 85),
   2 => array('userId' => 8, 'sum' => 41)
);

$dummyArray = array();
foreach ($sumArray as $sumKey => $sumValue)
{
   $dummyArray[$sumKey] = $sumValue['sum'];
}
array_multisort($dummyArray, SORT_DESC, $sumArray);


$count=0;
foreach ($sumArray as $sumKey => $sumValue)
{
   $count=$count+1;
   $rank=convert_number_to_words($count);
   echo $rank.' winner $sum='.$sumValue['sum'].'<br/>';
}
```

Function from referred with http://www.karlrixon.co.uk/writing/convert-numbers-to-words-with-php/

```
function convert_number_to_words($number) {

    $hyphen      = '-';
    $conjunction = ' and ';
    $separator   = ', ';
    $negative    = 'negative ';
    $decimal     = ' point ';
    $dictionary  = array(
        0                   => 'zero',
        1                   => 'First',
        2                   => 'Second',
        3                   => 'Third',
        4                   => 'Fourth',
        5                   => 'fiveth',
        6                   => 'sixth',
        7                   => 'seventh',
        8                   => 'eighth',
        9                   => 'nineth',
        10                  => 'tenth',
        11                  => 'eleventh',
        12                  => 'twelvth',
        13                  => 'thirteenth',
        14                  => 'fourteenth',
        15                  => 'fifteenth',
        16                  => 'sixteenth',
        17                  => 'seventeenth',
        18                  => 'eighteenth',
        19                  => 'nineteenth',
        20                  => 'twenty',
        30                  => 'thirty',
        40                  => 'fourty',
        50                  => 'fifty',
        60                  => 'sixty',
        70                  => 'seventy',
        80                  => 'eighty',
        90                  => 'ninety',
        100                 => 'hundred',
        1000                => 'thousand',
        1000000             => 'million',
        1000000000          => 'billion',
        1000000000000       => 'trillion',
        1000000000000000    => 'quadrillion',
        1000000000000000000 => 'quintillion'
    );

    if (!is_numeric($number)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (($number >= 0 && (int) $number < 0) || (int) $number < 0 - PHP_INT_MAX) {
        // overflow
        trigger_error(
            'convert_number_to_words only accepts numbers between -' . PHP_INT_MAX . ' and ' . PHP_INT_MAX,
            E_USER_WARNING
        );
        return false;
    }

    if ($number < 0) {
        return $negative . convert_number_to_words(abs($number));
    }

    $string = $fraction = null;

    if (strpos($number, '.') !== false) {
        list($number, $fraction) = explode('.', $number);
    }

    switch (true) {
        case $number < 21:
            $string = $dictionary[$number];
            break;
        case $number < 100:
            $tens   = ((int) ($number / 10)) * 10;
            $units  = $number % 10;
            $string = $dictionary[$tens];
            if ($units) {
                $string .= $hyphen . $dictionary[$units];
            }
            break;
        case $number < 1000:
            $hundreds  = $number / 100;
            $remainder = $number % 100;
            $string = $dictionary[$hundreds] . ' ' . $dictionary[100];
            if ($remainder) {
                $string .= $conjunction . convert_number_to_words($remainder);
            }
            break;
        default:
            $baseUnit = pow(1000, floor(log($number, 1000)));
            $numBaseUnits = (int) ($number / $baseUnit);
            $remainder = $number % $baseUnit;
            $string = convert_number_to_words($numBaseUnits) . ' ' . $dictionary[$baseUnit];
            if ($remainder) {
                $string .= $remainder < 100 ? $conjunction : $separator;
                $string .= convert_number_to_words($remainder);
            }
            break;
    }

    if (null !== $fraction && is_numeric($fraction)) {
        $string .= $decimal;
        $words = array();
        foreach (str_split((string) $fraction) as $number) {
            $words[] = $dictionary[$number];
        }
        $string .= implode(' ', $words);
    }

    return $string;
}
```